# Open office calc dynamic cell selection

Tags: openoffice-calc

So I have what I think is a pretty simple problem in open office calc I want fixed, but I can't find the answer anywhere.

If this is my table:

```
A  |  B  |  C

5  |  2  |  ?

3  |  1  |  ?
```

I want C to get the value of the B next to it and get the value of A{that number}.

So it should look like this:

```
A  |  B  |  C

5  |  2  |  3

3  |  1  |  5
```

EDIT:

I'll try to explain better. So what I want cell C1 to do is to get the value of B1. Then, it takes that value, call it X, and gets the value of the cell AX. Where A is the column. So in this case, C1 gets the value of A2 and C2 gets the value of A1.

Comment: Please expand and clarify your question as I can't figure out what it is that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the answer:

the formula should be `=INDIRECT("A"&B1)` in the cell C1 and then copied to the C column